# How can i use/ call maps api in my search box using javascript code to show list of cities

Tags: javascript, rest, api, frontend, web-deployment

[image]

i m trying to use Rapiapi in my webapplication and trying to use the javascript code to get the name of cities and country by autocomplete but im getting error when i try to search. will anyone be able to help me please.

please find the detail code below

```
var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://countries-cities.p.rapidapi.com/location/country/GB/geojson?format=json",
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "countries-cities.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "65a1b9fb01mshdd797ad52c65502p1489acjsna4edfe314956"
}
```

}

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});

function search() {
    var input = document.getElementById('search-bar');
    var allcities = new cities(input);
}
```

im trying to get the details of cities and country name as the user type in. T

Please help Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using their [SDKs](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/nodejs-request).

They provide the following snippet:

```js
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  method: '{{HTTP_METHOD}}',
  url: '{{API_URL}}',
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': '{{API_KEY}}'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```